# leaving a review using reputation system in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rating, review

I have a Rails 4 app. I'm using reputation system gem to add review functionality to the app. Each User can leave a rating (1 to 5) for each Store. I want each User to be able to also write a review (String/text) in addition to the rating. What's the best way to do that? Can I use reputation system or should I create my own review system?

Answer (score 1):

Using reputation system shouldn't prohibit you from also storing a text review. For instance you could create a Review model that has a rating (integer) and a review (string). A store could then have many reviews which it uses to compute it's reputation.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used [activerecord-reputation-system](https://github.com/twitter/activerecord-reputation-system), but it looks like really nice.

The RailsCast episode that covers activerecord-reputation-system, also shows a "From-Scratch Solution" if you want to roll your own. The [comments](http://railscasts.com/episodes/364-active-record-reputation-system?view=comments) for that episode list some other alternatives.

Whether you create your own review system or not really depends on your project needs. Personally, I would try to use the gem unless I had a compelling reason not to. I.e., if the competitive advantage of my system was a cutting edge reputation system with unique requirements, then I'd roll my own, otherwise I'd use  the gem.